# How to unlock a file locked in Visual Studio Online?

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I have a file in Visual Studio Online (visualstudio.com) locked by a Microsoft account user from a PC both of which do not exist any more.

[image]

How do I remove the lock by Microsoft account H.....w?

Answer (score 1):

Since the user account and PC are gone, the associated workspace should be deleted -- which will undo (lose) the pending changes, including the lock.

You can use tf.exe to delete the workspace. It's usually located under the Visual Studio install folder in Program Files(x86), or open a Developer Command Prompt for VS and it should be in the path there.

Something along the lines of:

```
tf.exe workspace /delete /collection:<VSOnline/Azure Repos URL> CUSTOMER-PC;H...w
```

The syntax is a little tricky sometimes -- docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspace-command?view=azure-devops).

Comment: This does not work when the account have been removed. At least I was not able to make it work

Comment: I've always used tf.exe to clean up abandoned workspaces from machines and users that no longer exist.  It should work, but as I mentioned the syntax can be tricky.  Did you get a specific error message?  Sometimes it helps to use the workspaces (note the s) command to get a list to help with the syntax.